# How to make zero by zero devision result in zero in Python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to divide one dataframe by another in Pandas to eventually represent a percentage change. Both dataframes values contain NaN and 0. Now, when I divide one dataframe by the other, the result where the value from both dataframes was zero is NaN. I know why 0/0 is set to np.nan, but from a percentage change perspective, I need 0/0 to be 0.

What is the cleanest way to accomplish this?

Reproducing the problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data_with_zeros = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2, np.nan, 0, 3], 'b': [np.nan, 2, 0, 6]})

data_with_zeros['a'].div(data_with_zeros['b'], fill_value=0)
```

Result:

```
0         inf
1         0.0
2         NaN
3         0.5
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Won't adding a `fillna(0)` at the end give you the desired outcome as all non-zero values in `a` would either become +/- `np.inf` when it encounters a zero value at `b`?

Comment: No, this would lead to values where both a and b values are missing to be set to 0 as well. Those values should remain NaN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach with [`dataframe.where method`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) -

```
mask = (data_with_zeros[['a','b']].values == [0,0]).all(1)
data_with_zeros['a'].div(data_with_zeros['b'], fill_value=0).where(~mask,0)
```

Alternatively `mask` could be created in a bit more intuitive way, like so -

```
mask = (data_with_zeros.a == 0) & (data_with_zeros.b == 0)
```

Sample runs -

Case #1:

```
In [66]: data_with_zeros
Out[66]: 
     a    b
0  2.0  NaN
1  NaN  2.0
2  0.0  0.0
3  3.0  6.0

In [67]: mask = (data_with_zeros.a == 0) & (data_with_zeros.b == 0)

In [68]: data_with_zeros['a'].div(data_with_zeros['b'], fill_value=0).where(~mask,0)
Out[68]: 
0         inf
1    0.000000
2    0.000000
3    0.500000
dtype: float64
```

Case #2:

```
In [70]: data_with_zeros
Out[70]: 
     a    b
0  2.0  0.0
1  NaN  2.0
2  0.0  0.0
3  3.0  6.0

In [71]: mask = (data_with_zeros.a == 0) & (data_with_zeros.b == 0)

In [72]: data_with_zeros['a'].div(data_with_zeros['b'], fill_value=0).where(~mask,0)
Out[72]: 
0         inf
1    0.000000
2    0.000000
3    0.500000
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the solution provided by Divakar, this function uses that method to do a dataframe/dataframe division:

```
def divide(a, other, fill_value=None):

    serie_name = a.name
    mask = ((a == 0) & (other[serie_name] == 0))
    result_with_zeros = a.div(other[serie_name], fill_value=fill_value)
    result_filled = result_with_zeros.where(~mask,0)

    return result_filled

data_with_zeros.apply(divide, args=(data_with_zeros,))
```

Result:

```
    a   b
0   1.0 0.0
1   NaN 1.0
2   0.0 0.0
3   1.0 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `inf` values

```
In [61]: data_with_zeros['a'].div(data_with_zeros['b'], fill_value=0).replace({np.inf: 0})
Out[61]:
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    NaN
3    0.5
dtype: float64
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. I need 0 / 0 to be 0. x / 0 is allowed to be inf

Answer (score 0):

If missing value can be treated as 0, you can probably do

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2, np.nan, 0, 3], 'b': [np.nan, 2, 0, 6]})

def percent_change(s1, s2):
    # Treat missing values as 0
    s3 = s2.fillna(0) / s1.fillna(0) - 1
    # If both values are 0, the perenctage change will be 0.
    mask = (s1.fillna(0) == 0) & (s2.fillna(0) == 0)
    s3[mask] = 0
    return s3


df['c'] = percent_change(df['a'], df['b'])
print(df)
```

Output

```
     a    b         c
0  2.0  NaN -1.000000
1  NaN  2.0       inf
2  0.0  0.0  0.000000
3  3.0  6.0  1.000000
```