# Pandas, timedeltas, and dividing by zero

Tags: python, pandas

**Update: Apologies for the confusion this question caused: The issue was that the `timedelta` fields I was looking at had been cast into pandas as (non-timedelta) objects. Recasting them to time deltas resolved the issue**

I have the following pandas dataframe:

| index | proactive_time | passive_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foo | timedelta(seconds=30) | timedelta(seconds=20) |
| bar | timedelta(0) | timedelta(0) |

And I'm looking to calculate the percentage of proactive time over proactive+passive time via:

```
dataframe['proactive_ratio'] = dataframe['proactive_time'] / (dataframe['proactive_time'] + dataframe['passive_time'])
```

The row `foo` works just fine, however `bar` returns a `DivideByZero` error. Fair enough - but I'd like those values to return <del>timedelta(0)</del> `NaN` instead of throwing the error.

This is where my lack of pandas knowledge presents problems: I can solve this via python conditionals in a `for` loop, but for performance reasons, I'd really prefer to keep this in pandas.

The strategies I've tried (eg .apply) seem to only have knowledge of one column at a time, which makes combining proactive_time & passive_time unfeasible.

Any thoughts on how to resolve?

Comment: "Fair enough - but I'd like those values to return timedelta(0) instead of throwing the error." - but the other values are floating-point ratios, not timedeltas, yeah? And when you get a zero ratio in the result, what's your plan for knowing whether or not the `passive_time` was zero? Did you consider `NaN` as a result instead? I would say that's pretty much what it's for.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel You're absolutely right - apologies, I rushed out the above explanation. Yes: the return should be NaN, not zero. Will update

Comment: In that case - isn't it already working that way, per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41376510 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas should already be doing what you expect. Make sure to use a recent stable version:

```
pd.__version__
# 1.5.3

df = pd.DataFrame({'proactive_time': [pd.Timedelta('30s'), pd.Timedelta('0s')],
                   'passive_time': [pd.Timedelta('20s'), pd.Timedelta('0s')]},
                   index=['foo', 'bar'])

df['proactive_ratio'] = df['proactive_time'] / (df['proactive_time'] + df['passive_time'])
```

Output:

```
      proactive_time     passive_time  proactive_ratio
foo  0 days 00:00:30  0 days 00:00:20              0.6
bar  0 days 00:00:00  0 days 00:00:00              NaN
```

Comment: It's unusual, I see most version issues due to (very) old versions. Glad you could identify the issue. You might want to report this on the pandas bug tracker (if you use the current dev and this wasn't already reported) ;)

Comment: Update: i thought this was a problem with pandas 2.0.0rc0, it turned out to be an issue with data formats. My timedeltas were being returned as objects, not timedeltas, which was causing the issue

Comment: I'm listing this as correct, but for the record: my question was flawed. In my case, the 'timedelta' fields were in fact (non-timedelta) objects. If anyone has the same issue, my suggestion would be to check your objects really are the data type you think they are

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, that's why it's important to always provide reproducible examples (`df.to_dict()`) :)

Answer (score 0):

In earlier versions of pandas, when you divide by zero, pandas returns NaN (Not a Number), which is a common way of representing missing or undefined values. However, in newer versions of pandas, division by zero now raises an exception, which is a deliberate change made for consistency with other programming languages and to improve the correctness of calculations.

If you want to keep the old behavior of returning NaN when dividing by zero, you dont need to reinstall the older version of pandas instead you can use the numpy library . and use its seterr() method. this will make it as floating point number and handled the errors via setting different parameters in seterr() method like...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'proactive_time': [pd.Timedelta('30s'), pd.Timedelta('0s')],
                   'passive_time': [pd.Timedelta('20s'), pd.Timedelta('0s')]},
                   index=['foo', 'bar'])

# Override division operator to return NaN instead of raising an exception
np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')

# Divide column A by column B using numpy
df['proactive_ratio'] = np.divide(df['proactive_time'],(df['proactive_time'] + df['passive_time']))

# Print the dataframe
df
```

**Output:**

```
     proactive_time     passive_time       proactive_ratio
foo  0 days 00:00:30     0 days 00:00:20    0.6
bar  0 days 00:00:00     0 days 00:00:00    NaN
```

Comment: "*However, in newer versions of pandas, division by zero now raises an exception, which is a deliberate change made for consistency with other programming languages and to improve the correctness of calculations*" can you source your claim with an official reference?

Comment: [link]https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html#whatsnew-100-divide-by-zero-raises-exceptions

Comment: you link is for pandas 1.0 (more than 2 years old, we're at 1.5.3 now), and I don't really see the relevant part in your link